# Connection bluetooth SPP on android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Sorry friends to bother you. I am stay at home mom and new in Android development which I took us  as part time job. I have expereince in Java development.

I have tried to look that bluetooth chat example and searched here a lot about from where to start.
The bluetooth chat sample never shows up the list of paired devices when I tried to run on my mobile. Whereas here in lot of questions there is thing UUID is used. I am not able to find out from where my friends retreived it.

My question is can someone guide me just few lines from where to start, I have a SPP device paired/unpaired (Idont know its UUID) I wish to connect it through my mobile. Just few lines of assistance is requested as time of you people is very precious, I understand it is my stupid question.

Thanks.

Comment: What profile are you trying to use?

Answer (score 3):

i use bluetooth spp in my app and get my data binary, so i can drop you some lines of code i use.

```
private BluetoothSocket sock;
private InputStream in;
private BluetoothDevice zee;

    /*
     * ****PAIR DONGLE****
     */

    zee = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("YO:UR:MA:CA:DR:ES:S");

    m = zee.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
            new Class[] { int.class });
    sock = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(zee, Integer.valueOf(1));
    sock.connect();
    int temp = 0;
    in = sock.getInputStream();

    try {
        while (true) {
            temp = in.read();
            //do what you like with your byte stored in temp
    } catch (IOException e) {}
```

hope that helps